# Class constructor optional parameter

Tags: typescript

I want to be able to initialise a class with or without value. If you pass a value then all methods of this class will expect this value as an argument and the value will be of the type you passed with initialisation.

If you pass nothing then methods are not going to expect any arguments and the value will be undefined.

I think some code will make a better example:

```
class Foo<T = void> {
  constructor(public type?: T) {}

  bar = (type: T) => {
    if (type) {
      this.type = type;
    }
  };
}

const fooUndefined = new Foo();

fooUndefined.bar(); // no errors, this is ok
fooUndefined.type === undefined; // no errors, this is ok
fooUndefined.bar(1); // expected error, this is ok

const fooNumber = new Foo(0);

fooNumber.type === 1; // no errors, but type is `number | undefined`, this is not ok
fooNumber.type > 0; // unexpected error because type is `number | undefined`, this is not ok

fooNumber.bar(1); // no errors, this is ok
fooNumber.bar(); // expected error, need to pass number, this is ok
fooNumber.bar('1'); // expected error, strings are not acceptable, this is ok

const fooUnion = new Foo<'a' | 'b'>() // no error, unexpected because it should not allow it
fooUnion.type.charAt(0) // unexpected error 

const fooUnion2 = new Foo<'a' | 'b'>('c') // expected error, this is ok
fooUnion2.type.charAt(0) // unexpected error
```

So the `type` property in `fooNumber` example is of type `number | undefined`. Is there a way to narrow it to `number` without explicit typecasting?

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD28A8AVaBeaA3eBLAJgHzQDeAUNNMPAHYQAuATgK7D3yMAUADswEYhcwaPQCe3AKYB+AFzQUASlIBfMhWh8wjDNE5jJcxRmLlKlXADNd+iUtNnK9ABa4IAOhs6bAbnWVV-r6qZNR09NAWiACqNPgSFrg0Evg6SQDucIicCr5kkfAxcQlJ+G6aXDnQAPRV0DTw0BKMjBwQedGx8YnJHuISGOiYzJ3Fyd7VtfWNza3tBSPdpeWcAIyVNY0AHpJsydMtjAA0Ii4wrtDwANZqoQwRiAByzAC2fE2pEhkI8JwADDlqfJPV5NXqSAaYFbjDZTJoHCDHPjMcKec4AAxoLze2gAPtBhkVFmjjs5zud6uErnNgdiwf1iL9obVhhJthJdik4RwNOywMwIP1UTAMVj3niCV0SsSTmSYBSLtdqaLGGUtKt1pMGlzGG0gcrVRUmVsdvQ9trjkk9uxoNxIHLlSTTtBzlS9SCVcsAOQrT0a43s02cmZHaAMRiJADmMC0-XlYGAwAk3HoYAEEkdsoVN1od3yMVwtA+X0QSE9YE90Dxnr4nsI2QmdS1weOLLZHJ5wD5Aud4QgTngzBAKTjIBA8AyuHoc3ztDpbmATi0AEF6H8lBtWyazcHoNmwvd5gWaAAmIuZZBlitVmt1z3AX0N1lboMHDNnGCujpH49zhfL1f-A2m4BtuBy7moZBAA)

Comment: all of the problems come from generic type `T = void`, that's why `fooUndefined.bar(); // no errors` doesn't throws any errors

Comment: It is ok that it does not throw, it is expected and correct behaviour. The thing I want to solve is `fooNumber.type` being of type `number | undefined`. Would be great to narrow it down to number somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't actually model that this way in Typescript, because what you would need to do is overload the class constructor, and you can't. You *can* solve this with an overloaded factory function:

```ts
class Foo<T> {
  public type: T;
  constructor(type: T) { // param is no longer optional
    this.type = type;
  }

  bar(type: T) {
    if (type) {
      this.type = type;
    }
  }
}

function makeFoo(): Foo<void>
function makeFoo <T>(type: T): Foo<T>
function makeFoo <T = void>(type?: T): Foo<T> | Foo<void> {
  if (typeof type === 'undefined') {
    return new Foo<void>(undefined); // explicitly pass undefined
  }

  return new Foo<T>(type);
}

const fooUndefined = makeFoo();

fooUndefined.bar(); // no errors
fooUndefined.type === undefined; // no errors
fooUndefined.bar(1); // expected error, this is ok

const fooNumber = new Foo(0);

fooNumber.type === 1; // no error now
fooNumber.type > 0; // no error now

fooNumber.bar(1); // no errors
fooNumber.bar(); // expected error, need to pass number, this is ok
fooNumber.bar('1'); // expected error, strings are not acceptable, this is ok

const fooUnion = new Foo<'a' | 'b'>() // error, no longer allows it
fooUnion.type.charAt(0) // no error now

const fooUnion2 = new Foo<'a' | 'b'>('c') // expected error, this is ok
fooUnion2.type.charAt(0) // no error now
```

Although I'm not sure how easy it would or wouldn't be to refactor your existing codebase to use such.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD28A8AVAfNA3gKGtADgK4BGIAlsNAC4Ce+ApgFzQoDcu0w8AdhFQE6FgVePwAUtBsxQBKLNAD0CgmH5gAttDIxu8aCB4Bzev2jx8VMjzAgOeKgAttAOkn1oAXmp167PAF9sDmJVCR9pORw8PDIAM2gwhki7aMcXN09vBj9owIDsQOxYwm5hK25odTAAa3oEeDEZZnqkADd4MgATNCKSsp5KmrrEaFQ0RKYWJrhEMd7SywGq2vrRlEz2rvG3AH4I5tn0aAAfGeRN7qwOOIS3eHiMjyfoAHISzvpYsm56Tpfk6LQfj0KiEfgVH4AdzObQ63TE70+31+MlYimU9AAHvhyMAyFQQDQVFBoIivj9OhxCnhgaDwdAoTD0BNUQUglxeFRoLFEABVbgfcm-TLLYYNVlFPkCpEU5whcSo9EMvQmfiiCCS+D8wXIzquHyeZ5k3VopTK6Cq9Wa7Uy35y0IARkVZqxDGEwst-AANNQnDBtGZquyeHxuYgAHKEdTEEyZRn1MQABglPPgkejJn1DENXgdpuUugt-DVpl0kM16Zj-Cz7gwifz5s9yvLFajVft4idDcLno1qcrmfljQbrvo7s6RZLPp+wpExJ0bZMPrS-pg8CD-cX1aHLwd-xH2LHVA9xdEPr4-G+hhgqncui5YGAwHoFjApHoy79WjXQewHNDqb8uUcb0NCLQvGALwnK8xAvOMcguqe3rmgY3DGKYNgGJC-pUNa3DlDWzjAA4qgAIJUEmCEFiqSHNsGnJhlq+E8AATCBYGzBBUGnC8sHjC8wD-Eqo7jpOZ6+gGAbrnh5QsYRxFkRRyZKj2tFltgQA)

Comment: Oh, that's clever, have not though in that direction at all! I guess I could maybe also make this function as static function of class. I'll experiment with it, thank you.

Comment: @Danila you absolutely can, unlike constructors static methods can have overloads. You may need to use separate classes still though and return the appropriate instance from the static factory method. Glad it helps!

Answer (score 0):

All condition params get SomeType | undefined.

You can write this way to bypass it.

Casting to number

```
fooNumber.type as number > 2
```

Or tell typescript you are sure there is available value using ! expression.

```
fooNumber.type! > 2
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but this won't cut it! Maybe there is another way to write the class, maybe with constructor overload or something, so you don't need to type cast anything